# O que significa "introspecção em tempo de execução"?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, lua

Procurando informações sobre um toolkit gráfico em Lua, encontrei uma explicação sobre o lgi (GTK) que apresentava uma grande vantagem: "...pois ele foi escrito em C e com capacidade de introspecção em tempo de execução, o que facilita a
criação de bindings para outras linguagens...".
Alguém pode me ajudar a entender melhor o que significa a "introspecção em tempo de execução"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A introspecção ou introspecção de tipos, permite ao programa examinar a estrutura de um tipo ou objeto em tempo de execução.

Por exemplo, em tempo de execução, é possível saber se um tipo X tem um método/função específica.

Um exemplo em python seria:

```
class foo(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.x = val
  def bar(self):
    return self.x

# dir permite a instrospecção
dir(foo(5))

# resultado
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__',
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__weakref__', 'bar', 'x']
```

A função `dir` permite entender o que o tipo `foo` contêm.

**Reflexão**

Introspecção não é o mesmo que Reflexão. A reflexão permite alterar os dados do tipo ou objeto em tempo de execução (os meta dados), a introspecção permite a consulta e análise das informações do tipo.